# What is wrong with this short Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, function, stylesheet, opacity

I've been looking at this JS and i'm trying to work out why it isn't having any effect.
It should - run the function at a specified interval and, until a certain element has 0 opacity it should keep decreasing the opacity of the element.

On firing this interval function, nothing happens on screen. Does anyone have any ideas?

```
setInterval(fadeover, 100);

function fadeover() {
    if (document.getElementById("rightopright").style.opacity > 0) {
        var curropac;
        curropac = document.getElementById("rightopright").style.opacity;
        document.getElementById("rightopright").style.opacity = (curropac - 0.1);
    }
}
```

I'm sure i'm doing something stupid here but can't work out what...
Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: try curropac  - parseFloat(0.1)

Comment: I'd say this is just too much code just to fade out something..

Comment: @techfoobar What would you suggest?

Comment: @Kolink - I'd suggest jquery's fadeOut, assuming there's more stuff in the app where jquery can pitch in heavily..

Comment: @Kolink - On a minimum, i'd suggest caching the `#rightopright` element.. *I see this is being done in your answer*

Comment: @techfoobar You do realise that jQuery's `fadeOut` is a LOT more code than my answer, right?

Comment: Ofcourse, i meant the amount of code the OP has to write..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably you haven't set a default value for the inline `opacity` property so it is an empty string (which is not a value greater than zero).

You need to test for that case:

```
function fadeover() {
    var el = document.getElementById("rightopright");
    var op = el.style.opacity;
    if (op === "") { 
        op = 1;
    }
    if (op > 0) {
        el.style.opacity = (op - 0.1);
    }
}
```

… or forget about JavaScript animation and do it with a [CSS 3 transition](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/) instead.

Comment: Maybe you should convert `op` first to number and then subtract...
`el.style.opacity = (+op - 0.1);`, if opacity already assigned it'll be string

Comment: The subtraction operator will [convert both its operands to Numbers](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.6.2) automatically. Explicitly doing so adds nothing useful.

Comment: Wow, what a fantastic response! Thanks to all who have responded. I assumed opacity took a basic integer value of 1 if it had not been set and was rendered to the screen - I was wrong. Yet again, a fantastic response from this community. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you specifically have `style="opacity:1"` on the element itself, `theElement.style.opacity` will be the empty string. The empty string is not greater than zero, so the function never runs.

Might I suggest the following:

```
function fadeOut(elem,time) {
    var opac = 1;
    setTimeout(function() {
        opac -= 0.1;
        elem.style.opacity = opac;
        if( opac > 0) setTimeout(arguments.callee,time/10);
    },time/10);
}
fadeOut(document.getElementById('rightopright'),1000);
```

Comment: Thanks for this insight, it has also helped me to understand the answer above :)